# Wkhtmltopdf + Docker Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownContentError

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I remove container and volume for one of my set containers (using docker-compose).
I "recreate", but I cannot be able to access to another container app url.
Docker network seems broken.
Here is the error :

```
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[==========>                                                 ] 18%
[===========================>                                ] 45%
[============================>                               ] 48%
[==============================>                             ] 50%
Warning: SSL error ignored                                        
[====================================>                       ] 61%
Error: Failed to load https://xxxxxx.....
...
...
Done                                                                      
Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownContentError
```

How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?